# jQuery and MSXML

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, msxml

MSXML6 is supposed to have the best security, performance, reliability, and W3C conformance ([Using the right version of MSXML in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)).

**Questions:**

1. Why does not jQuery use MSXML6?
2. Does jQuery use MSXML3? (I think the answer is  yes, see my update below...)
3. Can i fetch the version of MSXML from an [`IXMLDOMDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(VS.85).aspx) instance? If so, how?

**Update:**

I've made some research based on Deviant's answer:

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) creates the [`IXMLHTTPRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(VS.85).aspx) object, which was first released with [MSXML 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762314(VS.85).aspx), like this:

```
new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

`Microsoft.XMLHTTP` is a [ProgID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757837(VS.85).aspx), which is [only implemented in MSXML3 for legacy support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766426(VS.85).aspx) and not recommended. If i understand [the reference](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx) correctly this would have created a version 2.x `IXMLHTTPRequest` object, before those versions was [“kill-bitted”](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx). Now I'm pretty sure this ProgID creates an MSXML 3.0 `IXMLHTTPRequest` object. This may answer my second question.

Here is sample code that shows how to create the two recommended versions of the `IXMLHTTPRequest` object:

```
new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); // MSXML 3.0 ProgID...
new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); // MSXML 6.0 ProgID...
```

I've tested XSLT performance in MSXML3 vs MSXML6. MSXML6 used less than 1/10 of the time to do the same transformation as MSXML3 for a pretty large XML file!

**Rerences:**

1. [jQuery: The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library](http://jquery.com/)
2. [`IXMLHTTPRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759148(VS.85).aspx)
3. [MSXML API History](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762314(VS.85).aspx)
4. [GUID and ProgID Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757837(VS.85).aspx)
5. [Using the right version of MSXML in Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/xmlteam/archive/2006/10/23/using-the-right-version-of-msxml-in-internet-explorer.aspx)
6. [MSXML 3.0 GUIDs and ProgIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms766426(VS.85).aspx)
7. [MSXML 6.0 GUIDs and ProgIDs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms764622(VS.85).aspx)
8. [Why Version-Independent GUIDs and ProgIDs Were Removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761415(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 7):

jQuery does. Source:

```
// Create the request object; Microsoft failed to properly
// implement the XMLHttpRequest in IE7, so we use the ActiveXObject when it is available
// This function can be overriden by calling jQuery.ajaxSetup
xhr:function(){
     return window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : new XMLHttpRequest();
},
```

But it obviously can't use MSXML in Firefox/chrome/safari/opera etc. So if you attempt to use MSXML in your html your site will only work in IE. So I do not recommend you do that.

jQuery only uses MSXML as a backup to get around the bugs in MS's implementation of XmlHttpRequest.

I wouldn't say that MSXML is the most conformant to the XMLHttpRequest standard.
MSXML existed long before XMLHttpRequest did so it's an odd comparison. http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/

jQuery used to support XML and XPath selectors but that has been deprecated. There are plugins for jQuery and XML http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/xml+type:project_project

JSON is usually preferred over XML. http://json.org

Comment: IXMLHTTPRequest is part of MSXML

Comment: @knut he changed his question, so my answer is off

Comment: IXMLHTTPRequest is an interface in the Microsoft XML Lib, that has nothing to do with the Web Browser DOM object XMLHttpRequest that I linked in my answer. Your question is pretty broad and vague. What are you trying to accomplish? XML/XSLT vs jQuery/JSON ?  jQuery/JSON is the obvious choice.